# What type of plain text should the latex code be?

Tags: compiling, source

I know that one writes the LaTeX code in a text editor as plain text. One then saves this file as a `.tex` file ad compiles using latex (or pdflatex, or ...).

From what I understand, there are different types of plain text. What, technically, should the plain text for the tex-code be written as?

Comment: The easiest plain text is an `ASCII` code `.txt` file... making special characters difficult, but, it's LaTeX and that's what `\"a` is made for: ä etc. (As a German I need such 'special' characters as lot. Make sure your text editor uses the right encoding and it's ok for LaTeX nowadays as well

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Ok, so there isn't a "Standard" or a recommendation or something like that?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: Don't you think nowadays, the recommended way is `UTF8`? ASCII makes the code hard to read (and harder to type) as soon as you have accented characters, while all modern systems and editors understand UTF8.

Comment: The modern standard is `unicode` encoding and `xelatex` is able to understand this out of the box (using the right fonts etc. then). For `pdflatex` you need `\inputenc[utf8]{inputenc}` to get around and I could type `äöÜß` and even `→` directly without latex commands

Comment: @Bernard: See my addition ;-) The easiest is still ASCII. For my personal documents I still write `\"a` etc.

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: I don't agree with you. The easiest is UTF8: generally, when you have to type accented letters, you have the keyboard that give an easy access to these characters.

Comment: @Bernard: For a language like French or Spanish this is definitely true -- I rarely need accents (apart from the math versions). For Chinese letters/signs etc. ASCII ist not really appropiate, of course

Comment: Any purely ASCII-encoded file is automatically UTF8-encoded as well.

Comment: @Mico: You're cheating! ;o)

Comment: @Bernard I agree that UTF8 is easiest. I'm not sure that people generally have keyboards providing access to the characters they need. I often need some accented characters even though I write almost everything in English and my keyboard does not exactly make producing them easy. But since you can always use the macro forms anyway and often you do know how to insert the accented character, what's not to like about UTF8? Even if you plan to use only macros, using UTF8 allows you to change your mind easily later. Or to switch to a unicode engine. Why *not* UTF8?

Comment: What you ***don't*** want is the kind of 'plain text' which Word produces (or used to produce). The problem with that 'plain text' is that it is not really plain text at all....

Comment: @cfr: In my opinion, there's no reason again UTF8. What I meant is simply  this: when you very  often use accented letters, the reason is generally you type in *your* language and you have a compatible keyboard. Let me add I can easily type in Greek by switching the keyboard driver to a  French-Greek compatible driver (not Microsoft's Greek driver, of course!).

Comment: @Bernard Most keyboards in Wales are standard UK i.e. they do nothing to make it easier to type Welsh :(. I guess more common languages are better provided for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short version: it's complicated, but mostly systems automatically do the right thing.

---

Medium version:

There are only really two classes of differences in "types of plain text"  Line endings and encoding.

Line ending is what typically distinguishes plain text file transfer from "binary" as the line endings are converted to the format used on the platform,
typically this is (#13#10 pairs on windows, #10 on linux/and OSx and #13 on older mac releases, older operating systems had different conventions, or record based filesystems that did not use a lineend character at all.)

Modern TeX implementations will handle all combinations of #13 and #10 so even if you have a windows file on a linux machine (or vice versa it will work)

The other difference is encoding, that is what byte sequence is used to denote each letter. Here you can use most commonly used encodings, but you need to tell LaTeX which encoding you are using unless you only used ascii letters.

So if you are using UTF-8 (the best choice if you have no particular reason to choose something else) then you need

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

in the file.

if you are using ISO-8859-1 (latin-1) encoding used in most of Western Europe before systems started moving to Unicode, then you need

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

etc.

UTF-8 is preferred as it is a Unicode encoding rather than a language or region specific encoding. (Examples copied from this site will be in UTF-8 originally, although many editors will automatically convert if you cut and paste them into a file that is being saved with a different encoding.)

---

Long version: The Unicode spec.